# How can I add a Shared partition that Anbox can access?

Tags: linux, android-emulator

I know it's a relatively new and unstable application but I figured if anyone has suffered through the issue and solved it then they can help me too.

I've got [Anbox](http://anbox.io/) running and Apps open up really quickly but these apps can't access storage making them unusable.

[image: IMG:]

(Tap to Enlarge)

So is their a way I can make these apps access a certain folder or `.vdi` file or a partition? I'm trying to do this in Ubuntu 16.10 but it's still an Android Environment or Emulator,so  posting it here.

Answer (score -1):

I managed a limited workaround using ES File Explorer installed on Anbox and adding a shared folder via Network → LAN

Comment: Adding more details as to what the *limited* workaround was can help